# Python: Is it possible to skip values in tuple assignment?

Tags: python

I have a function which splits string in two parts at first encountered colon (skipping parts enclosed in brackets). This function returns tuple of three elements: index where the colon was encountered, part before colon and part after colon:

```
def split_on_colon(str):
    colon_ptr = find_separator(str, 0, ':')
    if colon_ptr == -1:
        return (colon_ptr, str, None)
    return (colon_ptr, str[:colon_ptr], str[colon_ptr+1:])
```

I call it this way:

```
def substitute_expression(expression):
    # Split function and arguments
    colon_ptr, func, args = split_on_colon(expression)
    ...
```

But sometimes it don't care about `colon_ptr` part.

Is there any simple construction in Python that would allow throwing away part of tuple in assignment, so that it wouldn't waste memory and variables namespace?

Something like this:

```
Ignore, func, args = split
```

Comment: This is usually done as this: ```_, func, args = split``` (which is seen often). But i'm not sure about the internals.

Comment: @sascha `_` preserves in `builtins` module and certainly consumes memory.

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks for this remark!

Comment: It's unrelated to your question, but it's a very bad idea to use `str` as a variable name, since it masks the builtin type of that name. Shadowing builtin names is permitted in Python, but it is discouraged since it is very bad style. It can cause some obscure errors if you edit this code later and try to use `str` for its normal meaning, not realizing you've given it a different meaning as a local variable.

Comment: @sascha Thanks for your comments. This will do.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Kasramvd: There is a built-in `_` variable in interactive mode, but assigning to `_` won't use that variable. It *will* assign to *an* `_` variable, and it will take memory.

Comment: @user2357112 In my case memory is not an issue. I was more curious what's the "proper" way to do it. But if it was global variable, if would have it's bad sides: good - if the function is called recursively, only one instance of global variable exists, bad - when the function returns, global variable remains and can't be disposed.

Comment: I know this is a 6-year old question. Still, I'd like to point out that your `split_on_colon` function is very similar to the built-in [partition](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method of string objects. I'm leaving this comment as a note to whoever arrives at this question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `_`, which is used to store unwanted values. Your statement will look like this:

```
_, func, args = split
```

Comment: Note that there is nothing special about `_`. It is just a preference/style that translates to *ignore the variable*.

Comment: Using `_` is not the best idea though, as it is very often used as an alias for `gettext`. This use is even mentionned in the official documentation: [“This function is usually aliased as _() in the local namespace”](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext). Use another name, such as `unused` or `dummy`.

Comment: @spectras I would argue the reverse, that aliasing `gettext` to `_` is not the best idea because `_` is often used to indicate a throw-away value.

Comment: @SethMMorton> afaik the official python documentation does not mention `_` as a throw-away value. It does explicitly mention it as a `gettext` alias, however (linked in my previous comment). Using `_` as a throw-away value also breaks the last-result feature of the interpreter. Sure, you might ignore python's own conventions, say you don't care about the interpreter and go with you own, but what's the point?

Comment: @spectras: TL;DR: `_` is not a python convention at all. 1) You are missing out the fact that `_` is an manual alias in **local namespace** (implying you/programmers do it, python doesn't). Python does not do any magic. 2) Further, it is only in REPL that `_` stands for last result. In real scripts/programs `_` means nothing special -- as I said in my first comment. 3) As for *throw-away/ignore* values, people have been using `_` for quite some time. As for `gettext`, I'd personally prefer using `t` instead of `_`.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan> `_` has been used as an alias for gettext for 26 years over many languages. On the other hand, `_` as a throw away is explicitly discouraged in python's official documentation, and the fact it is used by REPL shows it's not intended as a normal use for a throw away variable. There is this stackexchange question for further dicsussion: [is it bad practice to name an unused variable underscore](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147252/is-it-bad-practice-to-name-an-unused-variable-with-a-single-underscore).

Answer (score 2):

The best way for refusing of consuming extra memory is to handle this within your function. You can use a flag as an argument for your function then based on this flag you can decide to return 2 or 3 items.

```
def split_on_colon(my_str, flag):
    colon_ptr = find_separator(my_str, 0, ':')
    if flag:
        if colon_ptr == -1:
            return (my_str, None)
        return (my_str[:colon_ptr], my_str[colon_ptr+1:])
    else:
        if colon_ptr == -1:
            return (colon_ptr, my_str, None)
        return (colon_ptr, my_str[:colon_ptr], my_str[colon_ptr+1:])
```